# Post increment with example

Tags: java

I have a bit of confusion with the following expression. Here it is:

```
char a = 'D';
int b = 5;
System.out.println(a++/b+--a*b++);
```

I am trying to solve it in the following way:

1. `('D'/b+--a*b++);`

Behind the scenes,  `a = 'E'`

2. `'D'/b+'D'*b++;`
3. `'D'/b + 'D' * 5;`

Behind the scenes `b` value is incremented to 6, `b = 6`

4. `'D'/6 + 'D' *5;`
5. `11 + 'D' * 5;`
6. `11 + 345`

Since 'D' value is 69 in ASCII

7. `356`

But the compiler gives the output as 353. What is the mistake which I am doing it here?

Comment: Why not break this into multiple steps to improve readability and maintainability?  The next programmer that inherits this code is going to spend an hour googling "operator precedence" trying to figure out what this does.

Answer (score 4):

What you are calculating is

```
(a++ / b) + (--a * b++)
```

In this [expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html), `--a` cancels the `a++`: *After* the division `a` has the value `E`, but *before* the multiplication it again has the value `D`. Post increment and pre decrement cancel each other. So the first operand for `/`  and `*` each is `'D'` which is `68`. The post increment `b++` has no effect on the expression. So you do

```
(68 / 5) + (68 * 5)
```

which is `353` using integer rounding.

**Edit:** In detail, this is what happens:

```
char a = 'D';
int b = 5;

int divisonResult = a / b;

// a++ and --a cancel each other.
a++; // The incrementation of a happens after the divison.
--a; // The decrementation of a happens before the multiplication.

// Now a is back to 'D'.
int multiplicationResult = a * b;

b++; // This has no effect since b takes no part in the last step:

int additionResult = divisonResult + multiplicationResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Lurz Horn i made a mistake in my old answer, my tests passed because the error was less then 1 and was cut of by integer. So i quickly edited my tests and i'm working now with doubles.

It honestly interested me too so i took it apart step by step in the form of unit tests. The last test shows best how the compiler does it.

```
  @Test
  public void test1() throws Exception {
    char a = 'D';
    double b = 5;

    double result = a++ / b + --a * b++;

    assertThat(result, is(closeTo(353.6, 0.001)));
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() throws Exception {
    char a = 'D';
    double b = 5;

    double aDividedB = a++ / b;
    double result = aDividedB + --a * b++;

    assertThat(result, is(closeTo(353.6, 0.001)));
  }

  @Test
  public void test3() throws Exception {
    char a = 'D';
    double b = 5;

    double aDividedB = a / b;
    a++;
    double result = aDividedB + --a * b++;

    assertThat(result, is(closeTo(353.6, 0.001)));
  }

  @Test
  public void test4() throws Exception {
    char a = 'D';
    double b = 5;

    double aDividedB = a / b;
    a++;
    double aTimesB = --a * b++;
    double result = aDividedB + aTimesB;

    assertThat(result, is(closeTo(353.6, 0.001)));
  }

  @Test
  public void test5() throws Exception {
    char a = 'D';
    double b = 5;

    double aDividedB = a / b;
    a++;
    a--;
    double aTimesB = a * b++;
    double result = aDividedB + aTimesB;

    assertThat(result, is(closeTo(353.6, 0.001)));
  }

  @Test
  public void test6() throws Exception {
    char a = 'D';
    double b = 5;

    double aDividedB = a / b;
    a++;
    a--;
    double aTimesB = a * b;
    b++;
    double result = aDividedB + aTimesB;

    assertThat(result, is(closeTo(353.6, 0.001)));
  }
```