# Post Increment with substitution

Tags: java

I have a question here already of my own but I want to extend it [Post increment with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308967/post-increment-with-example)

```
char a = 'D';
int b = 5;
System.out.println(a++/b+--a*b++);
```

As one of the answers for the question is:

`(68 / 5) + (68 * 5)` and b++ doesnt have the effect on this .

My doubt is if b++ doesnt have effect then why a++ is having the effect?
Ideally it should have been

Step 1: `(68/b+--a*b++);`

Now a = 69;

Step 2: `(68/b+--a*5)`

Now a = 69;
    b =6;

Step 3: `(68/b+68*5)`

Step 4: `(68/6+68*5)`

Answer which 351 but the answer epected is 353

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confused [*evaluation order*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) with [*precedence*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Evaluation order states that *operands* are always executed **left to right**.

Precedence states that `*` and `/` *operators* are applied before `+` and `-`, unless overridden by parenthesis.

So, you're right that `a++/b+--a*b++` means `(a++ / b) + (--a * b++)`. That's *precedence*.

Since numeric operators [promote values to `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) (in this case), you're also right that `char a = 'D'` is equivalent to `int a = 68`.

So:

```
(a++ / b) + (--a * b++)    a = 68   b = 5
(68  / b) + (--a * b++)    a = 69   b = 5
(68  / 5) + (--a * b++)    a = 69   b = 5
(68  / 5) + (68  * b++)    a = 68   b = 5
(68  / 5) + (68  * 5  )    a = 68   b = 6
13        + 340            a = 68   b = 6
353                        a = 68   b = 6
```

As you can see, `b++` does have an effect: On the value of `b` *after* executing the expression.

Comment: @Andeas: Is it not the rule that precednce take priority over Associativity?

Comment: @user1400915 [*Associativity*](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) is about whether operators of equal precedence are executed left-to-right or right-to-left. Since your expression doesn't have consecutive operators of equal precedence, associativity is not involved here.

Answer (score -1):

Step 4: (68/6+68*5)   its your wrong!
b is 5 in all positions in the calculation instead of it's value 6.

so we have:

Step 4: (68/5+68*5) = (13+340)=353

Comment: Already covered in the question itself. OP is asking "why" the first `b` is 5 and not 6, and that is already covered too by another answer.